# .forEach() stops after first iteration

Tags: javascript, loops

A simple `.forEach()` stop after first iteration depending on the content...

My initial loop looked like this :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("app-form-to-js").forEach(function(node) {
    node.classList.remove("app-form-to-js");
    jsForms[node.id]=node.cloneNode(true);
    node.remove();
});
```

While the first loop occur, it doesn't go beyond.
Then, after some tweaking, I managed to get the loop working with this code :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("app-form-to-js").forEach(function(node) {
    jsForms[node.id]=node.cloneNode(true);
    jsForms[node.id].classList.remove("app-form-to-js");
});
```

But, the moment I use `node.classList.remove("app-form-to-js");` or `node.remove();` in the loop,
it will always stop after first iteration.

Any idea why loop is stopping after first iteration (so it iterate at least once) if I alter the node?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a live collection of elements. Which effectively means it changes as you mutate the DOM elements. You probably may want to copy the collection of elements then iterate them.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName(...).forEach is not a function` ?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` doesn't contain a `forEach` function...

Comment: try to use two separate **forEach** 1. for cloneNode and 2nd for remove class

Comment: are you using the f12 debugger to display errors while you are executing code?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, mwilson no, it doesn't produce any error. As I said, it iterate once at least.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 yes, I do.

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil yes, that will be last resort.

Comment: @zerkms doing mutations isn't the problem, as I want to do some (like removing a class, and remocing node from DOM). The problem is, from the moment I do a mutation, it will iterate only once, and won't do other nodes in DOM.

Comment: @Preciel mutation is certainly a problem (or at least one of them): `node.classList.remove("app-form-to-js");` after you do this - the current node is removed from the list, all others shift, and next iteration step skips the next node (because its index shifted).

Comment: To explain the liveness collection problem: imagine you have a list of 4 items: a, b, c, d. You're currently on the `i=1` (element b). You remove it from the live collection. Next iteration is `i=2`, which is now `d`, so the `c` element was skipped.

Comment: Yep, found the issue @zerkms, thanks to you and Jesse. You're right, `HTMLCollection` are directly altered, even by `node.remove()`, thus, it skip a count. I tried to copy a 3rd form, and I get 2 entry this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, which doesn't have a definition for `forEach`. You can however turn this into an array, which does have one defined, by using `Array.from()` like so:

```js
var collection = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("app-form-to-js"));
collection.forEach(function(node){...});
```

**EDIT:**

As was pointed out to me by @Preciel, the [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) object does have a `forEach()` function similar to an array. If you would rather use this, you can replace `document.getElementsByClassName("app-form-to-js")` with `document.querySelectorAll(".app-form-to-js")` and this will return a `NodeList` rather than an `HTMLCollection`

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("app-form-to-js").forEach(function(node) {});` do iterate though... As I said, it stop after first iteration, so it does iterate at least once. And as wrote in my second code exemple, loop works once I tweak it a bit. It doesn't tell me why the loop stop from the moment I alter or delete a node. Or is it just because it's a `HTMLCollection`?

Comment: Honestly, the code you posted shouldn't work at all according to the [JavaScript documetnation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). It may be doing only one iteration because `HTMLCollection` is a single object and foreach iterates through an array of objects, but your guess is as good as mine. The solution I provided is how this is most commonly done.

Comment: Seems to be fully supported to me: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach (except for IE, but who care about IE...)

Comment: An `HTMLCollection` is not the same as a `NodeList`.

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` gives you a `NodeList` though if you would rather use that than `getElementsByClassName()`.

Comment: Yes, seems to be the issue... While `HTMLCollection` share some common points, it's not a `NodeList`. As zerkms pointed in my question comments, `node.remove()` alter the `HTMLCollection` directly, thus, it skip a count. Using `querySelectorAll()` doesn't do that though. Will works better for my needs. (update your answer so I can valide please... ^^). Also, You can use `.forEach()` on `HTMLCollection`, it does have method, just like `NodeList`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to create an array using ES6 spread operator (this is my preferred method):

```
const elements = [...document.getElementsByClassName("app-form-to-js")];
elements.forEach((node)=>{...});
//OR:
elements.map((node,i)=>{... return node});
//Etc...
```

If you use the .map() method, you can make changes directly to the elements and it will be reflected in the DOM etc. - very powerful technique (remember to return the modified node in the function)